# How to remember the value of a variable after reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular6

I want to memorize the value of the variable `loggedIn`, because the value of the corresponding function in `appComponent.html` depends on its value.Tell me please how to implement it?

**teamplate of app component:**

```html
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="btn btn-outline-success"
                   [class.btn-outline-success]="!this.loggedInService.loggedIn"
                   [class.btn-outline-danger]="this.loggedInService.loggedIn"
                   (click)="this.loggedInService.loggedIn ? logout() : logIn()">
                    {{this.loggedInService.loggedIn? 'Exit' : 'Enter'}}
                </a>
            </li>
```

**code of app component:**

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private loggedInService: LoggedinService,
                private router: Router) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    logIn(): void {
        this.loggedInService.login();
        if (this.loggedInService.loggedIn) {
            let redirect = this.loggedInService.redirectUrl ? this.loggedInService.redirectUrl :
                '/gallery';
            this.router.navigate([redirect]);
        }
    }

    logout(): void {
        this.loggedInService.logout();
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
    }
}
```

**LoggedinService:**

```js
export class LoggedinService implements OnInit {
    redirectUrl: string;
    loggedIn: boolean = false;
    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit(): void  {}

    login(): boolean {
        localStorage.setItem('login', 'true');
        return this.loggedIn = true;
    }

    logout(): boolean {
        localStorage.removeItem('login');
        return this.loggedIn = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: you may want to research cookies : D

Comment: Please note that your strategy bears enormous security risks. If you rely on a client side value of loggedIn being true or false, this could be easyly forged by a penetrator and unwanted things could happen like identity theft, data leaks and the kind. You possibly don't want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already stored `login` after the user logged in in the `LoggedinService`'s `login` method.

Now even if you reload the page, you will be able to get it from there using:

```
// Add this property in your app.component.ts
loggedIn = localStorage.getItem('login');
```

This will return 'true' if the user was logged in before the page reload.

You can then create these classes:

```
.btn-outline-success {
  background: 'green';
}

.btn-outline-danger {
  background: 'green';
}
```

And then in your app.component.html dynamically use these classes using `[ngClass]` syntax like this:

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <a 
    class="btn" 
    [ngClass]="loggedIn === 'true' ? 'btn-outline-success': 'btn-outline-danger'"
    (click)="this.loggedInService.loggedIn ? logout() : logIn()">
    {{this.loggedInService.loggedIn? 'Exit' : 'Enter'}}
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: I need to save button styles after reloading, they depend on the value of the variable, how to implement it?

Comment: @IgorShvets, I've updated my answer accordingly. Please check if that helps.

Comment: @SiddAjmera you can't use `this` in the template

Answer (score 3):

Use [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Example:

```
localStorage.setItem('loggedIn', loggedIn);
```

Answer (score 1):

## For Angular 6 run:

`npm install @ngx-pwa/local-storage@6`

## For Angular 5 run:

`npm install @ngx-pwa/local-storage@5`

add this to your app module:

`imports: [
    LocalStorageModule,
    //other module imports here
  ],`

## LoginService

```js
export class LoggedinService implements OnInit {
    redirectUrl: string;
    loggedIn: boolean = false;
    constructor(private localStorage: LocalStorage) {}

    ngOnInit(): void  {}

    login(): boolean {
        this.localStorage.setItem('login', 'true').subscribe(res => {
          this.loggedIn = true;
        });
        return this.loggedIn = true;
    }

    logout(): boolean {
        this.localStorage.removeItem('login').subscribe(res => {
          this.loggedIn = false;
        });
        return this.loggedIn = false;
    }
}
```

> Don't forget to add the import

`import { LocalStorage } from "@ngx-pwa/local-storage";`

> check the repository [here](https://github.com/cyrilletuzi/angular-async-local-storage)